# Spring integeration DefaultSoapHeaderMapper - getStandardRequestHeaderNames - override

Tags: spring-integration

in previous si versions (si 2.11 to be specific and spring 3.1.1) getStandardRequestHeaderNames could be overrided to include Additional Application specific objects in the si message header. Our application relied on this ability (may be wrongfully so) to override this method and supply a custom POJO to be carried downstream consisting of many splitters, aggregators etc. The app used an ws inbound gateway and used the header-mapper attribute to specify the custom  soap header mapper.

Any clues on the reasoning behind why getStandardRequestHeaderNames cannot be overriden?

Need some advise on how I can migrate this to the current spring release.
The requirement is to extract elements from soapHeader and map them to an SI message headers as an POJO and send it down stream.
All help appreciated.

Code Snippet:  Works with older versions of spring

```
<int-ws:inbound-gateway id="webservice-inbound-gateway"
        request-channel="input-request-channel"
        reply-channel="output-response-channel"       
        header-mapper="CustomSoapHeaderMapper"   
        marshaller="marshaller"       
        unmarshaller="marshaller" />



@Component("CustomSoapHeaderMapper")
public class CustomSoapHeaderMapper extends DefaultSoapHeaderMapper {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("CustomSoapHeaderMapper");

    public static final String HEADER_SEARCH_METADATA = SearchMetadata.HEADER_ATTRIBUTE_NAME;
    public static final String HEADER_SERVICE_AUDIT = "XXXXXXXX";
    // Use simulation if security token is set to this value
    public static final String SECURITY_TOKEN_SIMULATION = "XXXX";

    private static final List<String> CUSTOM_HEADER_NAMES = new ArrayList<String>();
    static {
        CUSTOM_HEADER_NAMES.add(WebServiceHeaders.SOAP_ACTION);
        CUSTOM_HEADER_NAMES.add(HEADER_SEARCH_METADATA);
    }

    private int version =SearchMetadata.VERSION_CURRENT;

    public void setVersion(int version) {
        this.version = version;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<String> getStandardRequestHeaderNames() {
        return CUSTOM_HEADER_NAMES;
    }

    @Override
    protected Map<String, Object> extractUserDefinedHeaders(SoapMessage source) {
        // logger.log(Level.INFO,"extractUserDefinedHeaders");
        // call base class to extract header
        Map<String, Object> map = super.extractUserDefinedHeaders(source);
        Document doc = source.getDocument();
        SearchMetadata searchMetadata = new SearchMetadata();
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        try {
            source.writeTo(baos);
            baos.flush();
            searchMetadata.setRequestXML(baos.toString());
            baos.close();
        } catch (IOException e1) {

        }
        //logger.log(Level.WARNING, "Incoming Message " + baos.toString());

        SOAPMessage soapMessage = ((SaajSoapMessage) source).getSaajMessage();
        // generate TransactionID with UUID value
        String transactionID = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        // logger.log(Level.WARNING, "TransactionID=" + transactionID);
        Date now = new Date();

        searchMetadata.setTransactionID(transactionID);
        searchMetadata.setRequestType(SearchMetadata.REQUEST_TYPE_SYNCHRONOUS);
        searchMetadata.setRequestTime(now);// initialize the request time
        searchMetadata.setReceivedTime(now);// mark time system receives request
        searchMetadata.setVersion(version);

        Map<String, Object> finalHeaders = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        finalHeaders.put(HEADER_SEARCH_METADATA, searchMetadata);

        if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(map)) {
            // copy from other map
            finalHeaders.putAll(map);

            // check if ServiceAudit is available
            SoapHeaderElement serviceAuditElement = null;
            for (String key : map.keySet()) {
                // logger.log(Level.WARNING, "SoapHeader.{0}", key);
                if (StringUtils.contains(key, HEADER_SERVICE_AUDIT)) {
                    serviceAuditElement = (SoapHeaderElement) map.get(key);
                    break; 
                }
            }


        }
        return finalHeaders;
    }

        // GK Key Thing here for performance improvement is avoiding marshalling
        public gov.dhs.ice.ess.schema.ServiceAudit ExtractAuditHeader(Document doc) {
        ....
        }
        return serviceAudit;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Share, please, some code how would you like to see that.

Maybe you can just implement your own `SoapHeaderMapper` and inject it into WS Inbound Gateway?

You can still reuse your logic and copy/paste the standard behavior from the `DefaultSoapHeaderMapper`.

**UPDATE**

The test-case to demonstrate how to add user-defined header manually:

```
@Test
public void testCustomSoapHeaderMapper() {
    DefaultSoapHeaderMapper mapper = new DefaultSoapHeaderMapper() {

        @Override
        protected Map<String, Object> extractUserDefinedHeaders(SoapMessage source) {
            Map<String, Object> headers = super.extractUserDefinedHeaders(source);
            headers.put("foo", "bar");
            return headers;
        }
    };

    mapper.setRequestHeaderNames("*");

    SoapMessage soapMessage = mock(SoapMessage.class);

    Map<String, Object> headers = mapper.toHeadersFromRequest(soapMessage);
    assertTrue(headers.containsKey("foo"));
    assertEquals("bar", headers.get("foo"));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. I really appreciate that . Will definitely post back the bare minimum code to high light the issue. I have very limited SI knowledge so please forgive the ignorance. I can easily extract the elements of interest from the incoming soap message header. extractuserDefinedHeaders is returning a Map <String,object> containing new elements.  I could not figure out a way to access the SI message in the SoapHeaderMapper. I even tried the same  custom SoapheaderMapper implementing multiple interfaces including plain headerMapper.

Comment: You don't need to worry about the message on this level. All the userDefinedHeaders will move to the message headers. You don't need to do that standard headers hack.

Comment: See requestHeaderNames option

Comment: Thanks. Removed the hack. SetRequestHeaderNames("*"); Still don't see the headers. All my headers are encapsulated in a POJO SearchMetadata.

Comment: Thanks Artem Bilan. We are using SAAJ 1.1. I am suspecting jar conflicts at this point. When I dump the final headers map that is returned by extractUserDefinedHeaders I see all the proper keys and values. Debugging thro I see AbstractheaderMapper (line 263) shouldMapHeader returns false. Not sure why at this ppoint :)